# git reports "No space left on device", but df -h says there is is 2.5G available

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, hard-drive, tmp

I have an EC2 node running Ubuntu 14.04. On a deploy this morning, I received the following error message from git fetch:

```
error: unable to create temporary file: No space left on device
```

I logged into the server and df -h indicates I have plenty of space:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  488K   99M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.9G  2.5G  67% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M  4.0K  497M   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Am I misreading df here? My understanding has been that /tmp on EC2 is resident on /dev/xvda1, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Please try df -i

Comment: What about the inode count `df -i`?

Comment: /dev/xvda1     524288 524247     41  100% /

Comment: That doesn't look good!

Comment: I am currently researching what to do about node counts. Thanks so much guys. If I get a solution I will answer my own question, or feel free to answer it if you would like.

Comment: We have loads of disk full due to inode exhaustion Q&A already.

Comment: @istheEnglishway Ok understood. Killing old kernels solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verify system inodes:

```
root #df -i /
```

If there is approaching 100% usage, try to using

```
xdiskusage /
```

To find out what is occupying the inodes.

There is, sadly enough, no way to increase the number of inodes on a file system once the file system has been created.

Except LVM, which can be expanding the number of inodes with resize2fs

Referred to:[No space left on device while there is plenty of space available](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Knowledge_Base:No_space_left_on_device_while_there_is_plenty_of_space_available)

Comment: What if I pathetically running out of space to install `xdiskusage` or `ncdu`?

Answer (score 0):

1. It could be some application is creating huge number of small files and completely exhausting the inodes. You may look for such rogue application and delete the unwanted files.
2. The inode limit can't be increased dynamically, however
   if you are using LVM you may think of increasing the size of the volume otherwise take a backup and create a new filesystem specifying higher inode limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find command to search for directory which has bulk files and you can perform clean up based on your standards

`find /dev/xvda1 -type f -size +1M -exec ls -ltrh  {} \;` 
and when you find the place or directory where you need to perform the clean up pass that directory path in source and you can perform the clean up

```
find /dev/xvda1/dummy -type f -size +1M -mtime +120 -exec rm -rf  {} \;
```

In the above command I am removing the files which are older than 120 from a directory called dummy